If a random variable converges to zero in probability what can we say about its almost sure boundedness?
First let me start with definitions that I will be using in the question.

A sequence of random variables $X_n(\omega)$ converges to zero in probability if for any $\epsilon>0$, and any $\delta>0$, there exists an $N_{\epsilon,\delta}(\omega)$ such that $\forall n\geq N_{\epsilon,\delta}(\omega)$, $\text{Pr}(|X_n|\geq \delta)\leq\epsilon$.

A sequence of random variables $X_n(\omega)$ is bounded in probability if for any $\epsilon>0$,there exist a $\delta_\epsilon>0$ and $N_\epsilon(\omega)$ such that $\forall n\geq N_\epsilon(\omega)$, $\text{Pr}(|X_n|\geq \delta_\epsilon)\leq\epsilon$.

A sequence of random variables $X_n(\omega)$ is bounded almost surely if for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, there exists $M_n\geq 0$, $\text{Pr}(X_n\geq M_n)=0$.


It is clear that 1 implies 2. It is also clear that 3 implies 2. I am curious about the relationship between 1 and 3. Any hints?

Neither $1.)$ implies $3.)$ nor the other way round. Consider for example $X_n(x)=1/\sqrt{nx}$ on $[0,1]$ with the Lebesgue measure.

And the sequence $X_n=1$ is bounded, but does not converge to zero in probability.

No, the first one is unbounded, but converges to zero in probability (even in $L^1$ and pointwise).

@SeverinSchraven Yes, I see it now. Both are great counter examples. Thank you so much. Would you kindly write them up as an answer so we can put this baby to bed?

Neither $1.)$ implies $3.)$ nor the other way round.
For example $X_n(x)=1/\sqrt{nx}$ on $[0,1]$ with the Lebesgue measure. These random variables are all unbounded. However, $X_n\rightarrow 0$ in probability (even pointwise and in $L^1([0,1])$).
On the other hand, $X_n\equiv 1$ on $[0,1]$ is bounded (even without the words in probability). However, $X_n$ does not converge to zero in probability. If you want an example where the sequence does not converge at all consider $X_n\equiv n$ on $[0,1]$ ($X_n$ is bounded).
